# Can a Sorcerer/Wizard prepare spells from another person's spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, multi-classing, sorcerer

Sam is a level 8 sorcerer that takes 1 level of wizard for his 9th level. He now has a wizard spellbook and all that. 
Walter the level 9 wizard has a thought. Walter hands Sam his own spellbook for a day.

**Can Sam prepare the 5th level wizard spells in Walter's book?** He has the spell slots and the book has the spells.

Not in the scope of the question: 
Number of spells preparable. Sam is a level 1 wizard with Int 14 - so, three spells. 
Walter is a curious wizard who is willing allowing this to happen. 
Sam can read the language in Walter's spell book.

Answer (score 6):

> You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class
>   individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class.
>   (PHB 164)

So **no**, to prepare a 5th level spell from your spellbook, you have to be a 9th level wizard.

Also, he cannot even write the spell in his book. From the Errata v1.0 to the PHB:

> The spells cop­ied into a spellbook must be of a spell level the
>   wizard can prepare.

Comment: No-one said anything about coping. Sam is preparing it straight from Walters book.

Comment: @Overthinks You can only prepare from your own book.

Comment: Hypothetically, let's say that Sam kills Walter in his frustration and takes his book for himself.  This let's us get back to the core issue.  Sam cannot prepare Wizard spells that a single class Wizard of that same level couldn't prepare.  With more Sorcerer levels, his power grows (higher level spell slots), but not his Wizard knowledge.

Comment: Now I'm having second thoughts about my previous comment.  I think that you might have to copy any spells that you find (even from other spellbooks) into your personal spellbook if **Szega**'s comment is correct, which I think it is without an errata or sage tweet.  The PHB does use **your spellbook** throughout the Wizard class writeup.  So this might just be a second reason that the Sorcerer can't cast high-level Wizard spells with just a dip.

Comment: @NickBrown see [Using an acquired spellbook](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106734)

Comment: @Szega - Yeah, that's about where my thinking ended up after about a minute following my quick response.